# Array type conversion in Swift

Tags: swift

```
class Model: NSObject {
    var numbers : Array<Int> = []
}

internal func test() {
    let model : Model = Model.init()
    model.setValue([1,2,3], forKey: "numbers")
    print(model.numbers)
}

test()//[1, 2, 3]
```

But if I change the above `var numbers : [Int] = []` to `var numbers :[Int64] = []`, it will crash. Why is that? How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you edit your question!, it is not clear at all. How can you start by "But if I change the above ...."!?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not use KVC in this case. Use the setter with dot notation.

Second of all, if you want `[Int64]` cast the type

```
class Model: NSObject {
    var numbers = [Int64]()
}

internal func test() {
    let model = Model()
    model.numbers = [1,2,3] as [Int64]
    print(model.numbers)
}

test()//[1, 2, 3]
```